# Issues on using operator<< for templates in C++ for a newbie

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I'm new in using templates and also overloaded operators for them. This is my simple code. I tried to write an `operator<<` for the type `T`, but faced some odd error!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class S {
    T val;

public:
    S<T>(T v) { val = v; }
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T& to) {
    return (os << to);
}

template <class T>
void write_val(T& t) {
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main()
{
    S<int> s1(5);
    write_val(s1);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know:

1. Why I face this error.
2. What that kind of error is.
3. And how to solve that and get the code run successfully.

Would you help me on above cases?

PS: This is a small part a bigger code. I separated this section because I think it is the source of my issue.

The error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00EEC529 in test3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00342F8C)
```

Comment: Please retype error instead of screenshot.  Screenshots don't google well.

Answer (score 3):

This overloaded operator:

```
template <class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T& to) {
    return (os << to);
}
```

calls itself recursively, you can see it in the *Call Stack* window. Read up on [Call Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to know how it works and why and when [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) occurs. I mean, this site is called Stack Overflow, didn't you ever want to know what it stands for?

**Solution:**

The `operator<<` should be doing some real work instead, printing `to.val`, I suppose. Since `S::val` is `private`, you'll also have to declare it as a friend function to `S`.

```
template <class T>
class S {
    T val;

    template <class U>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, S<U> const& to); // add some const

public:
    S<T>(T v) : val(v) {} // use member initializer list
};

template <class U>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, S<U> const& to) {
    return os << to.val;
}
```

Don't overload `operator<<` like this:

```
template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T& to);
```

Because that template will match (almost) everything.

Comment: I made val public but that error still occurs. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: *"The `operator<<` should be doing some real work instead, printing `to.val`, I suppose."* - I wrote. Did you do that, too?

Comment: The problem is not doing some work called real work! I need to learn that matter then I think for a better work using these new terms. :)  Your code doesn't work still :(

Comment: @franky Sorry for the error, [now it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f09fc951cc75448d).

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, T& to) {
    return (os << to);
}
```

The above is a recursive call. The function calls itself forever until the process eats up the call stack.

Comment: ... or is terminated manually for converting the computer into a very expensive space-heater, especially if the compiler succeeds in inlining.